# Maven war upload using ftp

Tags: java, maven, ftp

I am using maven and now I want to deploy war to server using ftp.

After lot many search I didn't found perfect answer however i found following answer [Using Maven for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405979/using-maven-for-deployment)

It is uses ant plugin and answer is also 4 years old, so right now is there any better option? Can someone please provide good reference for uploading war using ftp in maven? I hardly needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example page for it, see the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html)

Comment: I have already seen it and it is for uploading artifacts I want to deploy war at server using ftp

Comment: you mean to a webcontainer, not to an artifact repository?

Comment: Most webcontainers have other/better ways to deploy/undeploy. There is http://cargo.codehaus.org/ which is a unified interface for webcontainers. This often makes it harder to configure. For some webcontainers are specific plugins, like for tomcat and jboss. What's the webcontainer you are using?