# Maven deploy to remote host ssh(scp) not repository

Tags: maven, ssh, scp, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-wagon-plugin

I'm trying to copy a jar built by maven to a directory in a remote host, not a repository.  I tried user1050755 answer here [Using Maven for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405979/using-maven-for-deployment) which uses the maven-antrun-plugin and also I've tried the wagon-ssh plugin.  Below is the hopefully relevant excerpt from my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xd</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <fromDir>target</fromDir>
                            <includes>xml-to-json-transformer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</includes>
                                <excludes/>
                                <url>scp://spade.innoimm.local</url>
                                <toDir>/opt/xd/custom-modules/processor</toDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scp</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <scp todir="root@spade:/opt/xd/custom-modules/processor"
                                         sftp="true"
                                         keyfile="C:\MerucurioVagrant\repo\mercurio-vagrant\insecure_private_key.ppk"
                                         failonerror="false"
                                         verbose="true"
                                         passphrase="nopass"
                                    >
                                        <fileset dir="target">
                                            <include
                                                name="xml-to-json-transformer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </scp>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                            <version>1.9.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

For both plugins I get the same error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xml-to-json-transformer: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

But I don't want to deploy to a repository, I thought the antrun-plugin would just let me copy a file to a remote host with no restrictions, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the maven-antrun-plugin but used integration-test for the phase.  The maven command I used was `mvn package integration-test`. I also used the trust="true" attribute because I couldn't get rid of a jsch exception `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey:`. I posted a question about that here [JSch: UnknownHostKey exception even when the hostkey fingerprint is present in the known_hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475366/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey)

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <scp todir="vagrant@localhost:~/maven-scp"
                            port="2200" trust="true" keyfile="C:\keys\openSSH_pair1\open_ssh_private"
                            failonerror="false" verbose="true" passphrase="pass">
                            <fileset dir="target">
                                <include name="xml-to-json-transformer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
                            </fileset>
                        </scp>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scp</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use phase deploy ,you need distributionManagement  or altDeploymentRepository:
In your case , there are two solutions:

1. skip deploy phase like this:

   ```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>X.Y</version>
      <configuration>
         <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   <phase>deploy</phase>
   ```

To

```
    <phase>install</phase>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this problem?

I faced same issue at windows platform with Apache Maven 3.2.5

The reason is that maven can not detect <server> config at settings.xml

So My solution is below.

1. add ssh account to url.

```
    <configuration>
        <url>scp://root@192.168.56.102</url>
    </configuration>
```

2. mvn deploy

then typing password at command line.

Now, Im trying to figure out a better solution.

I hope so...