# Maven deploy, specify port

Tags: java, maven, deployment, repository

Reading [the deploy manual](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html) id like to specify a different port using

```
<sshArgs>-P 7221</sshArgs>
```

in the `settings.xml`.

But I get a

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy 
  (default-deploy) on project french-toast: Failed to retrieve remote metadata 
  com.foobar:french-toast:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata 
  com.foobar:french-toast:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to french-id 
  (scpexe://root@www.french.com/): Exit code: 1 - ssh: connect to host www.french.com 
  port 22: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

The port `22` is used.

How to change the port? What did I miss?

Comment: Why would you like to change the port? ssh port is port 22 ? Can you do an `ssh ...` manually?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? And your settings.xml?

Comment: By the way, why not using the ssh syntax user@host:port ? (or have you already tried it?)

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/1406397/1746118 might help.

Comment: @kh Wegen der verfluchten hacker.

Comment: @asettouf Afaik it must be set in the pom but i need it in the settings

Comment: What is "it" in your comment?

Comment: @asettouf "it" means the user@host:port. Complete sentence: *AFAIK the user@host:port must be set in the pom.xml, but i need it in the /home/user/.m2/settings.xml because noone should know the ssh-port of my server.*

Comment: I see, in that case, you could define in your settings.xml a profile active by default containing the values you want to hide from the pom, and then load the values from the settings.xml inside your pom.xml. Wouldn't it be a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the ssh argument for a port is `[-p port]` (**notice that your are using a capital P**), see [a man ssh page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1). Alternatively, you could also use the ssh syntax, i.e. `user@host:port`

Answer (score 0):

*Go to your deploy profile inside pom and in the configuration tag add  and specify the port.

```
<configuration>
               <user>serverusername</user>
                  <password>serverpass@$#</password>
                  <name>project.build.finalName</name>
                    <adminurl>localhost:7003</adminurl>      ---> Here is the answer                   
               <source>youdirectory/finalName.packaging</source>
</configuration>
```