# Good way to package all jar files necessary to run Hadoop MapReduce application?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar

Using Eclipse I have built a MapReduce app. that uses also HCatalog and Hive jar files. This app was developed in Eclipse project on a local Hadoop installation. All neccessary jar files were simply included in Eclipse project from directories where Hadoop and Hive are installed on local node.

Now I need to run this app. on multi-node Hadoop installed elsewhere. Please advise on the best way tp package all neccessary jars in a single app. Or should I set CLASSPATH on the node where I plan to run my app? It would be nice to build a single self-sufficient jar right in Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: The q. is on hold for some reason so I'll leave this as a comment. There are several ways to do that - take a look here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a very good build tool - http://maven.apache.org/
It can package all your classes in a jar and can also add all the needed jar libraries inside it.

You can convert your existing project to Maven, by right clicking the project and choose menu  Configure > Convert to maven project. And then add the needed dependencies in pom.xml.

An example dependencies would look like.

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also see http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/

Comment: How Maven can help me to move my app with all jars to another machine?

Comment: Maven helps to package all your needed class and libraries. For copying files to remove server using maven check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh

Comment: Thanks for the links. After conversion to Maven project Eclipse created a vanila pom.xml. Now I need to manually insert all dependenies in this pom.xml, correct? Looks like in this case  Maven does not help  much to package an app from Eclipse...