# Spark Maven and Jar Development Workflow with local and remote server

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

So I have a very basic question about how to most effectively work with a local spark environment along with a remote server deployment and despite all of the various pieces of info about this, I still don't find any of them very clear.

I have my IntelliJ environment and dependencies in need within my pom to be able to compile and run and test with my local within intellij. Then I want to test and run against a remote server by copying over my packaged jar file via scp to then run spark-submits.

But I don't need any of the dependencies from maven within my pom file since spark-submit will just use the software on the server anyway so really I just need a jar file with the classes and keeping it very lightweight for the scp would be best. Not sure if I'm mis-understanding this but now I just need to figure out how to exclude any dependency from being added to the jar during packaging. What is the right way to do that?

Update:
So I managed to create a jar with and without dependencies using the below and I could just upload the one without any dependencies to server after building but how can I build only one jar file without any dependencies rather than waiting for a larger jar with everything which I don't need anyway:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Creating a shaded jar file for spark is correct. If the libraries are on the server, use the correct `provided` attribute in the pom dependency. Oh, and Maven can execute SCP with a custom task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between maven scope compile and provided for JAR packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging)

Comment: thanks. but I can't use `provided` scope since I need it to compile for testing local within IDE. does that make sense? can you elaborate on how to exactly go about creating a shade for all of the spark libraries? will definitely look into wagon-ssh. didn't know about that.

Comment: The provided scope means they are not  packaged. They still need to be downloaded locally for you to compile the code

Comment: Thanks. so just to be clear. I have to shade all of the spark libraries and also use `provided` scope?

Comment: To the other question. https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things here.

The `provided` dependency scope will allow you to work locally and prevent any server provided libraries from being packaged.

Maven doesn't package external libraries without creating an *uber* or *shaded* jar.

An example of a good Spark POM is [provided by Databricks](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html)

Also worth mentioning, [Maven copy local file to remote server using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh)

See Maven Wagon SSH plugin

Comment: I know I could use my own spark libraries when I work local and point those jars within intellij but is that the only way to compile with `provided` scope? because when I switch my spark libraries to `provided` and I try to run it within Intellij I get a class not found error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$` unless I had my own spark jars as dependencies.

Comment: You would only get that error if you copied that pom I linked to and didn't check that it's using Spark 1,whereas your error is from Spark 2

Comment: definitely did not copy over the pom from databricks. I guess how do I tell intellij to use the downloaded spark jar files if the scope is `provided`?

Comment: It already does... I have it in mine pom files and it works. As I explained, provided only affects the runtime of the code, not the compilation

Comment: Are you trying to run the code in intellij? In that case, then yes, you're going to have missing classes

Comment: yes. trying to compile and run in IntelliJ so it looks like I have to add my own classes to Intellij and then keep everything I don't want packaged as uber jar as `provided` and then I can test local. was wondering if there was a way to not use my own spark installation but I guess that makes sense. Wasn't sure what the best workflow is when testing local with Intellij and then needing to package/scp for remote cluster.

Comment: You could define two separate pom files I believe, though never done it. One for local development and the other for remote