# Automate deployment of GWT web app

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am creating a GWT application in Eclipse. For the application to work, it needs to be deployed on a server that runs on my virtual machine. It uses our company's JS library, that only works in this specific environment, so I really need to compile the GWT app and deploy it to the server.

The app basically consists of following folders and files:
/war
---/images
---/resources
------/localization
------/mapdata
------/svgs
------/etc...
---/gwt-compiled-app-folder
---/index.html

I know I can have images and languages inside the GWT app but we do not want that as we may change some texts or images without the need for compilation in the future when the app will be finished.

So far my build and deploy cycle is:

1. Click GWT compile in Eclipse and compile the app.
2. In WinSCP manually copy the compiled folder of the app to the virtual machine server root.
3. If any other resource changes (images, localization, vector map data, json resources...) I also have to manually copy them to the virtual machine.

Since I do this like 200 times a day, I'm getting tired of it and I finally have time to improve it.

My question is how can I automate these steps? What tools should I use? I do not even know if the app can be somehow compiled from command line. Ideally I would like to run some command or file that will compile the app and deploy all the files (maybe only those that has changed or are different) to the virtual machine.

**EDIT:**
I finally got build by maven to work! So now I only need to know how to copy the files to the ftp.

Comment: Automate the process of build and copying the artifacts and other resources using maven or ant.

Comment: I am now trying to convert my project to gwt maven project, so then I guess I will be able to compile the app through command line. Is maven also able to upload files to the server?

Comment: Hope these link would be useful - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh

Comment: sounds promising, thanks!