# Copy compiled binary files to remote system

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing simple Java application in `Eclipse Oxygen`. I would like to ask `Eclipse` to copy binary files to testing machine automatically when it builds. How to achieve that? How to run script on remote `Linux` machine that restarts application when binary is copied?

UPD

Since Eclipse builds project very often I would like to have `Deploy` functionality according to request. How to achieve this option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909867/maven-copy-local-file-to-remote-server-using-ssh

Comment: SCP and SSH perhaps ?

Comment: Look for some Continuos Integration library, it's looks like to be what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 'Builders' page of the project 'Properties'.

You can add an 'Ant' script or a program to be run when the project is built along with the other builders.

Builders normally run quite a lot so you may want to turn 'Build automatically' off.

It is also possible to write an Eclipse plugin which contributes additional builder types - but that is more work.