# How to generate source code from template with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, code-generation

I have a file with a list of tokens:

**tokens.txt**

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and a template file:

**template.txt**

```
public class @token@MyInterface implements MyInterface {
     public void doStuff() {
        // First line of generated code
        // Second line of generated code
     }
}
```

I want to generate the following source code files to `target/generated-sources/my/package`:

- FooMyInterface.java
- BarMyInterface.java
- BazMyInterface.java

One of the generated source files look like this:

**FooMyInterface.java**

```
public class FooMyInterface implements MyInterface {
     public void doStuff() {
        // First line of generated code
        // Second line of generated code
     }
}
```

How can I do this with Maven ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is called filtering.  [You can read more about it here.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)  As you can see, you'll have to change the way you're doing some things.  The variables are defined differently.  You'll want to rename the file to a .java.

But then you've got another problem:  This will take a source file and replace the variables with literals, but it wont compile the .java file for you when you build your project.  Assuming you want to do that, [here's a tutorial on how.](https://connect.gxsoftware.com/Blogs/Bram-de-Kruijff/Maven-secrets-filtering-sources.htm)  I'm going to inline some of that tutorial just in case it disappears some day:

Example source file:

```
public static final String DOMAIN = "${pom.groupId}";
public static final String WCB_ID = "${pom.artifactId}";
```

The filtering:

```
<project...>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <!-- Configure the source files as resources to be filtered
      into a custom target directory -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>../filtered-sources/java</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  ...
  </build>
...
</project>
```

Now change the directory in which maven finds the source files to compile:

```
<project...>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
      <!-- Overrule the default pom source directory to match
            our generated sources so the compiler will pick them up -->
      <sourceDirectory>target/filtered-sources/java</sourceDirectory>
  ...
  </build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: Does this will generate only one file ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that requirement when I wrote this.  To do that part, it looks like this SO answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308368/maven-how-to-filter-the-same-resource-multiple-times-with-different-property-va