# Find and replace a jar file using Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, build-automation, maven-3, hotswap

Suppose you are working on a big project, which is run on some application server (let's say Tomcat, but it may be also Jboss, or Jetty, or something else). The project consists of a several wars, while each war contains a lot of jar. The whole thing is built using Maven and it takes a lot of time to build it all.

Now, suppose a developer makes a change in just one module that produces one small jar. To continue working and test the change, the developer needs to replace this jar in the relevant wars and restart server (sometimes it's sufficient to redeploy wars). It's much faster then rebuilding the whole application. I have seen a lot of developers (including myself) creating shell scripts for this task.

However, it could be much nicer, if it could be done automatically using maven. Let's say when running "mvn install" the plugin will also go to some predefined location (e.g. ${tomcat}/webapps) and search for all appearances of myjar.jar and replace them with a new version (We have multiple jars, remember?)

Does anyone know about such a plugin? Or may be about some other tool that can do the same task? Or some better idea how to do it?

**Updated:** Btw, If I don't find a solution, I'll probably implement it myself. So please let me know if you are interested. I'll need some beta testers :)

**Updated:** So I created the plugin myself. See http://code.google.com/p/replace-file-plugin/ Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a very dangerous and non-reliable approach. Hot replacement of just one library inside the application is against all principles of testing (especially regression testing)

Comment: I'm not talking about testing environment, but about the development environment. This is quite similar to the Hudson incremental build - it doesn't come to replace the full nightly build, but to provide a quick feedback.

Comment: I agree with yegor256 that this is not a very reliable approach, but it sounds like a shell one-liner to me, e. g. using `find` in `bash`.

Comment: @Axel yes, it can be done in one line script. But I'm looking for a maven way, so it can be used with a multi-module project without duplications.

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven

Comment: @Tarlog Could you simply run your one-liner using the [Maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) from your existing build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, any features I asked for in this question, I have implemented myself. See http://code.google.com/p/replace-file-plugin/
I'll appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/).  It rocks, reduces development/deployment time a lot.  There is a 30 day free trial, so check it out for free.  I purchased my own license, it took my company a few weeks to approve purchasing it, and I couldn't wait.

Seriosuly man, it rocks.  Read about it, it can do what you want.

Comment: 10x, I'll check it, not sure I'll get a budget for a license... :(

Comment: Yeah, like I said I purchased my own license. $60 bucks. If you spend time figuring out how to configure it right, it can hotswap for all of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write your script as a Ant build, you can use the [Maven Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to embed the Ant build in your build lifecycle.

Comment: The problem that I need to add antrun to each module, I cannot inherit it.

Comment: Also AFAIK ant doesn't contain "find and replace" target. It's not hard to implement it though.

Comment: If you're going to implement this, I think it's better to implement it as a Mojo.

Comment: Sure, this is exactly the solution I'm thinking about right now. I wander how none thought about it before...

Answer (score 0):

Let's narrow the scope to one and only war file, I think you'd scale this up to your scenario yourself with no trouble.

You may try this option: create a final assembly module which runs fast and combines all dependee modules into one war-file. Then, if you initially do mvn clean package install for the whole build, you'd have to mvn clean package install the changed dependee module and re-run the final assembly module to quickly get grab on the updated war. This is quite stateful build scheme (and thus error prone), but after some getting familiar with this approach to change propagation you'd probably think this is the most simple idea that might work, and work faster.