# Ant SCP task not working - where as I am able to scp using cygwin

Tags: ant, maven, scp, jsch

Please provide your expert option for a issue I am facing at work..

1. Ant SCP task not working - where as I am able to scp using cygwin.
2. Local Environment: windows 7 64 bit, Jdk 1.6.0.24, Ant-1.8.2 (with ant optional dependencies fetched), maven 2 (usign ant run plugin), jsch-0.1.44
   Remote Environment: VM Labmanager 4.0, Windows Server 2008 - R2, SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8, JDK 1.6.0.24
3. I have set password authetication to yes and restarted sshd on remote host.
4. Maven goal is as follows. (btw, I executed same ANT target as well, so Ant and Maven are giving the same result with jsch-0.1.44 and jsch-0.1.42 )

   ```
   <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>copy-installer</id>
           <phase>process-resources</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <target>
                   <scp file="readme.txt"  todir="devlocal@dev-jboss02.com:/home/devlocal"     password="password" trust="true"    verbose="true"  port="22"/>
               </target>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
           <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
           <version>0.1.42</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
           <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.2</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
5. Stack trace is as follows:

   ```
   $ mvn -e
   + Error stacktraces are turned on.
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   [INFO] Executing tasks

   main:
         [scp] Connecting to dev-jboss02.com:22
         [scp] Connecting to dev-jboss02.com port 22
         [scp] Connection established
         [scp] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8
         [scp] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.38
         [scp] CheckCiphers: aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
         [scp] aes256-cbc is not available.
         [scp] aes192-cbc is not available.
         [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
         [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
         [scp] kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
         [scp] kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
         [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
         [scp] expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
         [scp] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
         [scp] Permanently added 'dev-jboss02.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
         [scp] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
         [scp] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
         [scp] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
         [scp] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
         [scp] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
         [scp] Next authentication method: publickey
         [scp] Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
         [scp] Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
         [scp] Authentications that can continue: password
         [scp] Next authentication method: password
         [scp] Disconnecting from dev-jboss02.com port 22
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Trace
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fa
   il
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:283)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
           ... 17 more
   Caused by: C:workspace\trunk\pix-test-automation\target\antrun\build-main.xml:4: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Aut
   h fail
           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:245)
           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
   ```
6. Also on the sshd log, I see it says client is using JSCH-0.1.38, where client is using jsch-0.1.44, I dont have  JSCH-0.1.38 neither in ant lib's or in mvn repo anywhere..

   ```
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3224: debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3224: debug1: Forked child 3364.
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: Connection from **.**.**.** port 44082
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version JSCH-0.1.38
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: no match: JSCH-0.1.38
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   Sep 21 13:45:46 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: KEX done
   Sep 21 13:45:47 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: userauth-request for user devlocal service ssh-connection method none
   Sep 21 13:45:47 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3924: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
   Sep 21 13:45:49 DEV-JBOSS02 sshd: PID 3364: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for sjcgnaval1 [10.32.102.33] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
   ```
7. I am keen to get the password authentication and not key authentication, as this is a automation project where the VM image create for each run.

Regards, 
gnaval

Comment: There is no need to resort to `Ant`. You can use `Apache Maven Wagon` plugin. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468595/318054.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the JSch library where your ant installation can see it?  [Ant scp task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) clearly states that this is necessary:

> Note: This task depends on external libraries not included in the Ant
> distribution. See [Library Dependencies](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) for more information.

There, you'll find that

> jsch.jar 0.1.50 or later

is required for the SCP task.

[JSCh is available here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html):

Answer (score 0):

Try using Maven 3, Maven 2 embeds jsch 0.1.38 and it takes the precedence over the version specified in the plugin dependencies. This was resolved in Maven 3.