# Access Maven build properties in Jenkins post-build script to retrieve deployed artifact

Tags: maven, maven-2, jenkins

I've got a Maven project that Jenkins builds and deploys to a remote repository. I then need to copy the deployed .war to an external location. I've been trying to do this with a post-build shell script but I don't see any way to get the build information from maven (for example, the URL of the deployed artifact). Is there a way to get it, or a way to do this that's more integrated into maven? I can calculate the deployment path using Jenkins build parameters but it seems like a hack.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a maven build you should always find the build artifact at

```
target/<artifactId>-<version>.<packaging>
```

You can access this path within the maven `pom.xml` by using the maven [properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) (see [pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html))

```
${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}
```

To copy the artifact to another location after the build you can use several approaches described e.g. in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586202/367285).

Comment: According to the Jenkins log, the .war file gets built as target/artifactId.war (without the version). The only versioned resource is a .tar.gz inside target/assembly. This might be a result of  an oddity in our pom.xml.

Comment: Changing our .war file is going to be best, I think. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveMc Be careful in changing your war name. It might affect your application URL after deploying it into a container.

Comment: Thanks - we'll rename it before it gets deployed to a container; we never want more than one version running in a container.