# Copy generated jar or war files to target directory

Tags: maven, jar, maven-3, war

Below is my maven project structure:
  Main-Project
    Module1, 
    Module2, 
    Module3

All the above modules either generate jar or war files in the target directory of each module
I need to copy all the generated jar or war files to a any directory ex: {base.dir}

can anyone help me with mvn command & POM file configuration to achieve this task.

Comment: See [Best practices for copying files with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/a/694175/651140)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do something like this is to use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) for it. This way you could use standard Ant tasks to copy the files to any direction.