# How do I have Maven install and/or configure eclipse plugins automatically

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, configuration

I am new to eclipse and the interaction between eclipse and maven.

Is it possible to have Maven automatically install Eclipse plugins if the eclipse path is known?

Is it possible to configure specific project settings for each installed plugin when the eclipse project is created? Is it easy to update these configuration settings once the eclipse project is created?

How may I go about this using Maven? Or is it not possible/ideal?

Comment: Even there is a way, I will not recommend. Maven is a build tool and Eclipse is an IDE, I don't see any point why you want a build tool automatically alter the IDE without human intervention, at the time when project is created.

Comment: Yes, keep your build tool separate to your development tool. Think of the need to automated builds. You don't want to have Maven logic that forces someone to install Eclipse on your build server....

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin, you would have to copy the plugin files to the *eclipse/plugins* folder as described in the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins?)

You can use maven to copy the plugin files/folders to the eclipse plugins directory. This question will show how: [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven)

However, I would not advise to use maven to configure the IDE and its plugins, you should manage your projects and not your IDEs with maven.