# Build play! project with maven

Tags: java, maven, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using play 1.2.4 to create a web app. It works together with some other applications which are maven projects: they are compiled and resolved (dependencies) with maven.

Now I need to modify my play app so it can also be compiled and started with maven.

Therefore I download maven (3.0.4), installed the maven modul and did everything according to https://github.com/wangyizhuo/play-maven and http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head/home

I manage to automatically create a pom file in my project. The problem is that the jars from the play framework are not copied into the lib-folder and when I try to execute `mvn package` they are missing.

Is there a way to get the maven module to work properly? If not, is there another possibility to compile and start the project from maven (i.e. intermediate ant-file that can be executed by maven?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an old question, but did you solved this issue now ? I got the same problem.

Comment: I haven't found any working plugin/tool for that. So I ended up implementing my web app using a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven) explains it pretty well. I havnt looked at the module you are refering too, but this shows you how you can create tasks and inculde directories in your build.

Do you need to use maven to build/run it? If not it looks like there is a community contributed extension that allows you to [use maven](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head/home) from within play.