# maven deploy: how to restrict to deploy only the artifacts? (multi-module environment)

Tags: maven, deployment

I have a project with two modules: client and server. In the parent pom.xml I added info for the deployment phase, so as to deploy to a local directory:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.my</groupId>
  <artifactId>myTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>myTest</name>
  <modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>client</module>
  </modules>

<!-- for: mvn deploy -->
<distributionManagement>
    <repository> 
        <id> myRepo </id>
        <url> file:myDeployDir </url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn deploy` not only server-0.1.jar and client-0.1.jar get copied to `myDeploy` but a sum of 33 (!) files: *pom *sha1 *md5 *xml for pom, metadata and jar.

How can I set that only server-0.1.jar and client-0.1.jar should be copied?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is possible but not recommended. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You are deploying artifacts to a repository which means in Maven having the artifacts (.jar, .pom, .sha1, .md5 etc.). Furthermore i would recommend to use a repository manager instead of the file system. If you like having only the jar's you need to do it in a different way.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what the "deploy" phase actually means. I think that deploy is to put the final artifact (only the .jar) into the place where it is going to be used by the end user. I.E. if I develop a new unix command, then by deploying it, I understand to copy *only* the executable to (say) /usr/local/bin

Comment: if you only want to copy some artifacts to file:myDeployDir then the assembly plugin may be an option for you. It is also used to bundle deliverables. Or is file:myDeployDir some Tomcat/webapps folder and you try to deploy the application?

Comment: @wemu No, it is only to copy the file, but I thought that "deploy" may be just copy in certain cases, while in other do more complicated things. It is not a webapp,  I guess there is a standard pluging for deploying webapps. Thanks

Comment: then this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven may help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use maven [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html)

> deploy:deploy-file is used to install a single artifact along with its
>   pom. In that case the artifact information can be taken from an
>   optionally specified pomFile, but can be completed/overriden using the
>   command line.