# Can we build a war file of source code using maven command line at a specified directory?

Tags: java, maven

mvn package at specified location (ex. C:\Users\xyz)

For example

**mvn package** or **mvn compile war:war** command will generate a war file at ../projectName/target location

but insted of that target location can we specify our own location using command line ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Maven is convention over configuration. However you can copy the file afterwards, using a variety of mechanisms explained here: [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible out of the box. But you could prepare your POM for that:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</buildDirectory>
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        <directory>${buildDirectory}</directory>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

If you now do a simple `mvn package` it will behave as default: putting the output into the project's target directory.

But you also now can run a

```
mvn package -DbuildDirectory=<any other directory>
```

and all output is done to the new place. Note, that I said: *all output*! It is not only the artifact (the JAR or the WAR), but all compiled classes, the surefire reports, and so on.