# Maven copy two separate directories and their files in separate locations

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to copy two separate directories and their files in different locations directories using maven and not able to achieve this, can any body help here?

**src/com/smepath         ---- >   buildDirectory/install/****

**src/com/someotherpath   ----->   buildDirectory/xsd/****

Although there is a related question here ([Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven)) but doesn't solve my problem.

**I am trying to change following solution viz.**

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/install</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/common/install</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/${env}/install</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Like if I make one more similar entry for let say my second directory locations `xsd` then second one overrides first.

Also using an extra `<excution>` within `<executions>` or an extra `<configuration>` also not working.

Comment: Are you trying to copy resources to target/install or target/classes/install? Right now you are doing the former, so the result will not be part of the jar file that you're building.

Comment: That is deliberate and I don't want them in jar, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Adding a second `<execution>` should work.  What error/problem do you get when you try to add the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a second `<execution>` to your pom should work.
My guess is that you aren't specifying a unique `<id>` for each phase.

I have my project laid out like so:

```
src/main/resources/foo
                    |_a.txt
                    |_b.txt
src/main/resources/bar
                    |_c.txt
src/main/resources/baz
                    |_d.txt
src/main/resources/fum
                    |_e.txt
                    |_f.txt
```

After a `clean validate` I end up with my files copied like so:

```
target/location-1
               |_a.txt
               |_b.txt
               |_c.txt
target/location-2
               |_d.txt
               |_e.txt
               |_f.txt
```

using the following plugin definition in my pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources-1</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/location-1</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/foo</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/bar</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources-2</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/location-2</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/baz</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/fum</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

You should be able to use the above as an example to get your install and xsd files copied.

Comment: You are absolutely right and this is working for me now although I also had a different workaround which I would like to put here as an answer for future reference of any body but will go with yours one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using extra `<execution>` solution as suggested by @azurefrog but I was also able to achieve this using following solution.

Here I am putting my both directories `install` and `xsd` in a `resources` directory and using the stuff further viz.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/common</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>install*/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/${env}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>install*/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/common</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>xsd*/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```