# How to Copy files and directories using Maven as post-build or pre-build in a specific location?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, tycho

I have a `parent maven pom` and a `child pom`. I have to do some copying directory after `parent pom` but before `child pom`. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Or something that is similar that should be improved? Makes it easier for us if we have something we can start from, and not have to start from scratch.

Comment: I have not tried any, but found something here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven) which says copy can be done. Now searching for how to do pre or post build tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven defines a list of lifecycles that are executed in order when you tell Maven to build your project. See [Lifecycles Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html) for an ordered list of those phases.

If you run

```
mvn clean test
```

Maven executes all lifecycles up to and including `test`.

Assuming you have a multi-module Maven project and a sub-module needs to copy resources generated by the parent module before running its tests, you can use the `maven-resources-plugin` in your child module and bind it to the `generate-resources` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-from-parent</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources
                </outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../generated-resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `generate-resources` phase is executed before the `test` phase. So if you run

```
mvn clean test
```

in the directory of your parent module, this will copy everything from `<parent>/generated-resources` to `<child>/target/generated-resources` after your parent module ran and before the child module runs its tests.

Comment: Do we need to put this in Child POM or Parent POM?

Comment: The snippet needs to be in your child pom. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: If Child POM, how to make it as pre-build or post-build?

Comment: In Child POM it runs some test cases, I want this to happen before those tests run. This is my child POM http://paste.ubuntu.com/11908479/

Comment: I updated my answer again. Hope it clarifies the concept of lifecycles a bit.

Comment: It isn't working, I think I have to find a way to say that this need to happen just after mvn clean. It is trying to do my build first.

Comment: But this code you gave works in isolation, i want to bring it as a pre build. Can some one help in that. Thanks @hzpz

Comment: It is supposed to do (almost) exactly that. Please post both your parent and child pom.xml and the Maven command you are using.

Comment: This is the one you gave which copy works http://paste.ubuntu.com/11908583/ but it should be like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/11908596/ which is copying the files as post build not pre build which I want. The parent pom has nothing except calling this as a module.

Comment: You lost me. Which is your parent POM and which is your child POM? Why do you need to copy the resources after the parent if it does nothing?

Comment: This is my parent POM http://paste.ubuntu.com/11908696/ 
This is child POM http://paste.ubuntu.com/11908596/ 
In Child pom there are two plugins, how to make one plugin which is our copy run first and the other plugin run 2nd

Comment: Ah, now that seems like a different question than the one in your original post. The rcptt plugin also binds itself to the `generate-resources`. If two (or more) plugins bind to the same phase, the order in pom.xml defines the execution order. Specify `maven-resources-plugin` before `ci4rcptt-maven-plugin` and Maven will run the plugins in the right order.

Comment: This is my current POM http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913560/ where I have arranged in proper order. When I comment out (remove from compilation) one of the plugin, the other one is working fine. But when I include both of them, I get this http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913568/ which shows the copy has not happened and it is trying to access the directory where copied folder does not exist.

Comment: Ah, it seems the rcptt plugin is hijacking the `default-resources` execution which for some reason always comes first. Try to bind the resources plugin to the `initialize` phase and see if that works: `<phase>initialize</phase>`.

Comment: It says we have a duplicate phase http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913615/ - sorry my mistake - im running it, its compiling i will update once its finished.

Comment: As the error message says: you have a duplicate `<phase>` tag in your pom.xml. You must replace the old `<phase>generate-resources</phase>` with the new `<phase>initialize</phase>`, don't just add it.

Comment: Thank you so much hzpz . It hepled a lot.

Comment: what are the other phase than initialize? where can i find those?

Comment: See the link that I included in my answer: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: Actually it is not copying any .* files, i.e., hidden linux files. How to do that ?

Comment: Please create another question for that.

Comment: Sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961775/maven-copy-files-and-folders-plugin-not-copeying-linux-dot-hidden-files thanks