# How to create a jar with Maven that includes dependencies in a separate folder for each dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want build a Maven project with dependencies outside the `.jar`, but every dependency must be in a separate directory as:

```
libs/${dependency.groupId}/${dependency.artifactId}/${dependency.version}
```

Just like this:

```
/build
  my.jar
  /libs
    /org.yaml
      /snakeyaml
        /1.17
          snakeyaml-1.17.jar
    /etc...
```

I know that there is a `maven-dependency-plugin`, but how to configure it like that? Or there is any other plugin that can do this?

Comment: `my.jar` will not be an executable JAR since it won't contain itself the dependency classes. It sounds like you want to create an assembly, like a custom ZIP?

Comment: @Tunaki it don't need to contain dependency classes, in real project there will be launcher too, that will get all libraries and run that .jar with valid classpath. I will edit title.

Comment: Ok but I guess you need to package those inside a final container, like a ZIP or a TAR?

Comment: @Tunaki no, normal directory tree with all dependencies.

Comment: Just don't forget to distribute a copy of the licences and notifications too. Snakeyaml, for example, is ASL 2, and that has a requirement that you *must* include a copy of its licence in the distribution.

Comment: How are you building your final released archive then?

Comment: @Tunaki This is all I need, in future I might want pack everything from `/build` (including launcher and .jar) to single .zip, but that will be probably done via separate goal or utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want to do here is to create a custom archive for your project. For that, you want to use the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

There are multiple aspects to consider:

- You want a base directory of `build`. This is set by the [`<baseDirectory>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_assembly) parameter.
- You want to have all of the project's dependencies in a repo-like directory layour. For that, you can use a custom `outputFileNameMapping` for the [`dependencySet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet). This enables to use [a set of properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#outputFileNameMapping); in this case we're interested in the group id, artifact id and version. We need to disable `<useProjectArtifact>`, otherwise it would also include the project main artifact.
- For the main artifact, we simply use a [`<file>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html#class_file) element, pointing to the main artifact of the project.

The assembly descriptor would look like:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format> <!-- to turn into final archive type -->
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>build</baseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
        </file>
    </files>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.groupId}/${artifact.artifactId}/${artifact.version}/${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Note that it uses a `<format>` of `dir`, meaning that it does not "package" the output structure inside an archive but leaves it as a directory structure. In the future, you'll be able to customize this assembly descriptor with your launcher scripts and make a final archive of it by changing this format to the one you'll want.

Finally, the configuration of the plugin itself will be

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor> <!-- path to the above assembly descriptor -->
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With such a configuration, launching `mvn clean install` will output the wanted directory structure inside `target/${finalName}`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use that in multi-module project with parent poms, I keep getting `Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: B:\path\artifact-1.0.pom`, adding it to exception list seems to not change anything.

Comment: ok, I think that I got this, but I needed to create additional project that will be executed last and use this plugin in it. So thanks ;)

Comment: one lest question if you are still here, there is any way to move that `baseDirectory` outside `artifact/target` directory?

Comment: @GotoFinal That is a different concern. Everything generated by Maven should be placed inside `target`, and you really don't want to do otherwise. Generally speaking, when you have a final artifact, "moving" it outside of `target` means, in the Maven lingo, deploying it, with the help of `maven-deploy-plugin`: it will push your artifact to configured remote repositories. In this particular case of a directory structure, you could potentially use the `maven-antrun-plugin` and have an Ant task to copy it somewhere (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/694175/1743880)).