# maven-assembly-plugin: is there a way to have loops?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a bunch of modules in my setup, and I'd like to copy a file to each of these modules. As copying is mostly done by using `maven-assembly-plugin`, I'd like to use it here as well.

However, I noticed that the plugin does not allow any loop mechanism such as for-each or so. Therefore when we have, let's say, 50 modules, we have to repeat coding `fileSet` tag 50 times, which looks lame and unprofessional.

For instance, consider the below descriptor. The snippet copies the `config.properties` file to one of the modules (`project.base`). However, I have a lot of modules in my setup, so I need to do the same operation for each of them. This leads to a situation where I need to copy-paste the `fileSet` 50 times, which is outrageous.

```
<fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>../project.base</outputDirectory>
            <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <includes>
                <include>config.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
       <!-- Same to be repeat for every module here-->
    </fileSets>
```

Is there a way to automate this? Or was it designed to operate this way?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/586202/1988304) is useful

Comment: see also [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html) and this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Comment: I saw both, but I cannot use `ant-plugin` as I am told not to, and as for `resources-plugin`, the [same](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) situation persists. I guess you just have to copy-paste the same tag for each copy.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this copying over and over? It sounds like architecture is wrong ?

Comment: Because the config file is to be put under every module's directory after the compilation process.

Comment: Not only this file,sometimes you just need to have the copy of a certain file in every directory. It's not the first time I am encountering such a situation. And I am quite shocked to see that maven is unable to handle such a trivial task, apart from utilizing Ant.