# How to unpack just the files from a sub-folder in maven-dependency-plugin with goal unpack-dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

How to unpack files from a sub-folder into a target folder?

Example:

My package includes `ThisFolder` and `ThatFolder`, I just want to unpack the folders and files from `ThisFolder` into the target directory, not the folder `Thisfolder` itself.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack_this</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <configuration>
          <includeArtifactIds>ZipFile</includeArtifactIds>
          <includes>ThisFolder/**</includes>
          <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

In this example I'm almost there, but `ThisFolder` is included. If I try to use:

```
<excludes>ThisFolder</excludes>
```

it just doesn't work. Is there a solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven Dependency Plugin is made for dependencies, i.e. Java archives. The directory structure inside a Java archive is essential for the class files' package structure. So, it's easy to comprehed why the directories in your archive are considered by the plugin and cannot be suppressed.

The cleanest way I can think of at the moment is to copy the files afterwards. See [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven).

(Another one is to use the Exec Maven Plugin with a `zip.exe` but that would introduce an external dependency.)

I'd prefer a solution with the [Wagon Maven Plugin's `copy` goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/copy-mojo.html) as described in [fnt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468595/1744774) to the question linked above.