# Copy a folder from one module to other module in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

Project structure

```
-MyProject
    |_ project1
            |_ dist
            |_ app
            |_ config
            |_ pom.xml
    |_ project2
            |_ pom.xml
```

I tried another way as below, but didn't work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-jar</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/assets/</outputDirectory>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want to copy **dist** from **project1** to **project2** using maven. Could anyone tell me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What does dist contain? If it's need in project2 which isn't it there?

Comment: dist folder contains webapp files and above pom file is from project2

Comment: Than my question: Why not moving those files into project2 which I suppose is a WAR packaging module?

Comment: How can I do like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dist</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/assets</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../project1/dist/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use the [Wagon Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/index.html) for such:

> Use this plugin to view and transfer resources between repositories using Maven Wagon.

See also this [answer to *Best practices for copying files with Maven*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468595/1744774).