# Use profiles properties for different enviroments in Maven for Selenium/Cucumber

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber-jvm, maven-profiles

I create tests using Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber-jvm, built on Maven.
I want to achieve next:

I want to have profiles with properties and use this properties in my steps depended on enviroments.

I've created a folder in `src/test/resources` and added 2 subfolder in it: `Staging` and `Dev`.

In each folder I have a file `config.properties` where I have saved `username`.

My POM looks like :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now I want to change properties of profiles to something like this:

```
<properties> test/resources/dev/config.properties</properties>
<properties> test/resources/staging/config.properties</properties>
```

And I want when I run my test with an active staging profile in my step defs when I call:

```
system.getProperty("username")
```

I want this to return `username` which is provided in staging's properties.

When I run this when `dev` profile is active, I want to get `dev`'s property.

Comment: You say "_I've created a folder in `src/test/resources` and added 2 subfolder in it: `Staging` and `Dev`._" and later "_`<properties> test/resources/[dev|staging]/config.properties</properties>`_". Where is this folder in the latter and what are the sub-folders' real names, with leading capitals or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add properties to your profiles, e.g:

  ```
  <propertiesFile>staging.properties</propertiesFile>
  ```

  ```
  <propertiesFile>dev.properties</propertiesFile>
  ```
- Name the different properties files accordingly and place them in `src/test/resources` directly.
- Copy the according properties file to `config.properties` with one of the options described in [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468595/1744774) by using `${propertiesFile}`. I prefer the Wagon Maven Plugin.

**UPDATE**

That means: Forget about the two extra directories containing the two properties files. Put them both in `src/test/resources/` and copy them according to:

#### `staging`

`src/test/resources/staging.properties` copied to:

- `src/test/resources/config.properties`
- or to `target/config.properties`

depending on the phase you bind the copy process to.

#### `dev`

`src/test/resources/dev.properties` copied to:

- `src/test/resources/config.properties`
- or to `target/config.properties`

depending on the phase you bind the copy process to.

Comment: hi. I don't understand your second step. I have two directories -  src\test\resources\configs\staging\config.properties - for staging enviroment and -src\test\resources\configs\dev\config.properties - for dev enviroment.  I want the next - when I execute from comand line -Pdev which activate dev profile, I want in my code system.getProperty() to return properties from dev configs. When I activate staging profile, I want to get properties from staging configs. How Can I achieve it?

Comment: @SornoDavid I know what you want from your question. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Now I understang what you suggest.But I don't want to use copy or something.I'l mark this answer as right answer,because It works. But I'm trying to change and copy properties files automatically. I saw this link - https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/ which might helps me. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @SornoDavid What do you mean by "_automatically_"?. Nothing happens automatically in IT unless you implement it. And I gave you a link in my answer that shows a few ways how to implement exactly what you want. What's wrong with copying? BTW, since you're new to SO: Do you know that you can show additional appreciation by also upvoting an accepted answer, see also [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: in automatically I mean that I won't have to copy something from something to something. I want when I build my project, my project would be able to deside which properties are needed for the build. Again,thanks for your answer.I tried upvoteing when I accepted this post as answer,but I'm not able as my reputation is under 15.Thank you again

Comment: @SornoDavid I see. I wasn't aware of this 15 rep limit. Now you are able to. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like this:

1. Use Spring Boot [external configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config). We could set up either `application-{profile}.properties` or `application-{profile}.yaml` according to your preference. Put the environment variables (e.g. hostname, uri, credentials etc) over there. And if we need variables for all the environments, just put them in `application.properties` or `application.yaml`.
2. Use the maven argument `spring.profiles.active` to activate the profile accordingly. The following command is one use case in CI/CD:

   `mvn clean verify -Dspring.profiles.active={profile} ..........`