# How to rename a file while unpacking an artifact with maven-dependency-plugin?

Tags: maven

I'm using a `maven-dependency-plugin` to unpack a jar that contains several `.sh` scripts and that works as expected.

So I'm able to copy the files into the `<outputDirectory>${project.build.dir}/main-scripts</outputDirectory>`

But now I want to rename only one of them from `run.sh` to `run-main.sh` while unpacking. How could it be achieved with the dependency plugin?

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.main.libs</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>main-scripts</artifactId>
                                    <version>LATEST</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <includes>*.sh</includes>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.dir}/main-scripts</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for copying files with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven)

Comment: Why do you like to unpack an artifact?

Comment: @khmarbaise to get the scripts and use them further in a processing pipeline

Comment: Why are scripts in a build process needed? In particular in a jar file packaged? Does not make sense.